# Redemption MAPIFolder.IsSharePointFolder() analogue

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

Is there an analogue of MAPIFolder.IsSharePointFolder () in Redemption?
I need to determine if the folder is a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation folder.
I looked in RDOFolder methods but didn't find needed.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint folders are fake read-only folders that are only accessible through the Outlook UI or OOM (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.issharepointfolder?view=outlook-pia)

Since `RDOFolder` only wraps real MAPI-based folders, a folder in Redemption will never be a Sharepoint folder.